# TypeScript console log only in development mode

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, console, console.log

Is there a way to only output TypeScript/JavaScript console logs when Webpack bundles with mode development, but omit console logs with mode production? I have comments that I often use for status messages within my app and I do not always want to erase them for every production version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
let isDevMode = process.argv[1].endsWith('webpack-dev-server') || process.argv[1].endsWith('webpack-dev-server.js');
```